# Ubuntu 14 command line printing impossible but fine through gui

Tags: command-line, printing

If I try to command line print any file using lp or lpr, I get a "no pages found" error in CUPS. Tried also as SUDO, no go.

But if I print from any application (text editor etc) it prints no problem.

```
The job is queued at the correct printer with a status of "No pages found!"

▼ ID ▼  Name    User    Size    Pages   State   Control
till-143    Unknown     Withheld    1k      Unknown     processing since
Mon 17 Nov 2014 12:29:32 PM CET 
"No pages found!"
```

The printer is a USB Bixolon SRP350iii+ ticket printer, but I've tried it with other models and the issue is the same. Doesn't matter whether printer is local (USB) or network.

System is Ubuntu 14.04. Latest version of Bixolon Linux CUPS driver as supplied by them. I've uninstalled and reinstalled both the drivers and CUPS. Problem continues. Any ideas please?

```
From the error log:
    D [17/Nov/2014:12:27:02 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
    D [17/Nov/2014:12:27:02 +0100] [Job 142] Set job-printer-state-message to "Waiting for printer to become available.", current level=INFO
    D [17/Nov/2014:12:27:02 +0100] Discarding unused job-progress event...
    D [17/Nov/2014:12:27:02 +0100] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
    D [17/Nov/2014:12:27:02 +0100] cupsd is not idle any more, canceling shutdown.
    E [17/Nov/2014:12:27:02 +0100] [Job 142] No pages found!
    D [17/Nov/2014:12:27:02 +0100] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
    D [17/Nov/2014:12:27:02 +0100] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
    D [17/Nov/2014:12:27:02 +0100] [Job 142] Set job-printer-state-message to "No pages found!", current level=ERROR
---
```

Comment: Have you tried contacting their support? If their official driver is not working for you, it might be a good idea.

Comment: No, I'm sure it's a misconfiguration on this machine somewhere, but I **don't know where arrrgh!**